# Views bonus pack CSV export internal server error

Tags: views, 6

I'm using the CSV export feature in the views bonus pack, but when I go to the path I set up for it I get this error message:

"The website encountered an error while retrieving http://something.com/csv. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

I'm successfully using this module on a different site, and as far as I can tell they have the same configurations. It used to work on this site and recently broke for no apparent reason. Any ideas on what the potential points of failure might be to cause this error?

Comment: You should post details, like the error message from the logs

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down votes. There are no errors in the log. Is there some information I'm not thinking of I should include?

Comment: Try going to the url and see what happens

Comment: I navigate to the url and it loads for 5 or so seconds, then gives me a 500 error, but nothing in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was Theme Developer being on.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you're having an internal server error (fatal PHP error) on the URL it's trying to use. The reason is most likely faulty data, you can find the exact cause by looking in the error log of your webserver.